# How to find Xpath for nodes with text including linebreak or html fomatters

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to locate a specific node content from an html response. I am trying to find a bit difficult to locate a very specific node as the node element contains line breaks. I am trying out in [xpathtester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/a098dad1834d3ef09f276f4a1a39e560) site and my test xml is a provided below.

```
    <html> 
      <table > 
        <tr > 
          <th colspan="3"> 
            <table  > 
              <tr  valign="bottom"> 
                <th   scope="col" align="left">Test
                  <br/> Item1</th>  
                <th   scope="col">:</th>  
                <th   scope="col" align="left">ABC123</th>  
                <th rowspan="7"> 
                  <img width="100" height="140" src="xyzcontenturl.jpg"/> 
                </th> 
              </tr>   
              <tr  valign="bottom"> 
                <th   scope="col" align="left">Test
                  <br/> Item2</th>  
                <th  scope="col" >:</th>  
                <th  scope="col" align="left" colspan="2" >DEF789</th> 
              </tr> 
            </table> 
          </th> 
        </tr>  
    </table>  
      <p> 
        <strong/> 
      </p> 
    </html>
```

The idea is to pick up the third column header text and i can place a condition //th[contains(text(),"Test")]/following-sibling::th[2]/text() to locate that(value returned is ABC123).

The challenge is when i try to locate the value based on a specific node ie. "Test Item1" .
Since the Line break is sitting between The text "Test" and "Item1" I could not use functions "contains or starts-with.

**How do I write the XPATH so that i can pick up the TH element with value `"Test                 <br/> Item1"?**

Note: The xml provided is a sample illustrating the problem hence first table header ( th element) or second Table Header (th) element etc won't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare against [`normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) which replace newlines (not HTML `<br/>` to be clear) with single space :

```
//th[normalize-space()='Test Item1']/following-sibling::th[2]/text()
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/885fca80ce1fe83060088dd2890829d3)</kbd>**

The function receives concatenation of all text nodes within `th` as argument, do *whitespaces normalization* on the argument and return the result. Quoted from the linked specification :

> The `normalize-space` function returns the argument string with whitespace normalized by stripping leading and trailing whitespace and replacing sequences of whitespace characters by a single space.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XPath in code, then get the element and use the "InnerText" property.
If from XSL use the text() function.
What are you calling your XPath from?

Comment: I am looking for a generic xpath expression that can do the trick without shifting the evaluation logic to code.

Comment: I'll assume "generic" = XSL since you seem averse to code.  Try text() or as har07 mentions normalize-space() from XSL.